# C# "Thread.Sleep" Messing My Program (Form Doesn't Show Up)

Tags: c#, forms, timer, delay, thread-sleep

i add a loop to my program just to check something...(For verification)

```
for (int i = 1; i < total; i++){
   for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++){
      for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){ 
           pixel = block[i][row][col];
           label1.Text = pixel.R.ToString("X");
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);}}}
```

After Add this loop program works , but form doesnt show up. I Start Debuging and i saw that in this line it stops. Dont go any further.

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Basicly begining of the program. So I isolate the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);}}}`
Part it is working now. Why this code is causing problem. I used the
 `using System.Threading.Tasks;`.
Any idea or i can use other delay function... İ waiting for your help. Thank you..

Comment: Which function is this snipped from?

Comment: this loop is in the main function , in "private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)"

Comment: Don't block the UI thread; Your form doesn't open because it waits for your callback to finish before it can continue showing and drawing your form.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: You should remove the `Sleep`.

Comment: :) then what i will use instead , to delay showing the results 100ms apart

Comment: If thats the only purpose of the sleep, I'd make the callback async and use `await Task.Delay(100);` istead

Comment: This is gonna be my first program in c# , so can you give the code , the function and the calling the function in main program pls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never, ever, block the UI Thread (by means of sleeping or doing some heavy work) as the Thread can only either handle UI-Events (clicks, rerendering, resizing) **or** run your code, not both. In cases where you must execute some long running code from a event-handler, you can either start a new thread to do the work or run async code.

For you, something like this should work just fine:

```
public async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int i = 1; i < total; i++){
       for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++){
          for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){ 
               pixel = block[i][row][col];
               label1.Text = pixel.R.ToString("X");
               await Task.Delay();
          }
       }
    }
}
```

While `Sleep` blocks the thread while it waits, `await Task.Delay();` does *not*. It actually returns and lets the thread continue doing whatever it was doing previously and *notifies* the thread when it finished waiting so the thread can come back to your function later and continue running your code. (This is a simplification of how async and await works in C#)

Comment: No, this won't work. You'd need to put the whole block of code (the three for-loops) in its own async function and call it.

Comment: what if i can't change the form1 to private async void. Because when i do that it gives lots of errors. There are other codes in it... Is there any other way ? For Example creating this await Task.Delay function , and call it from there ?

Comment: well i miss C sometimes :( .

Comment: Ok thanks for all your help. my last question is is there much differance between private async void Form1_Load and publick void Form_Load ? Because i don't know why it gives that much error when i change it. But i'll sort it out. I think 1 sleepless night again

Comment: Which errors are you getting? It shouldn't produce any errors by just making the function async. If it was public previously, you can keep it that way. You only have to add the `async` keyword to make `await Task.Delay();` work.

Comment: Alright , errors are because of the privte-public thing. i made it public every thing is working now perfectly. thanks very much...